# How to set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH properly (concept)?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, teamspeak

I have Qt Creator and Qt 5.5 installed.

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH = C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\plugins
```

If I disable the environment var, I do get an error when I launch an application from QtC. So the variable seems to be required.

My problem is:

1. When I run other Qt based applications (i.e. Teamspeak or such), those fail, I always have to disable (delete) `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` first
2. When I use KITS in QtC and switch between Qt versions (i.e. 5.4, 5.6) the variable is not in sync with this very version

How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to set it on the QtC Project page for that specific build

[image: Project Page]

Answer (score 1):

My decision that helped me. It:

1. In the search for Win 10 enter sysdm.cpl
2. Advanced -> Environment Variables -> to System Variables -> add:
   PATH
   C: \ Users \ ~ \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ Lib \ site-packages \ pyqt5_tools \ plugins \ platforms \ (your address to qminimal.dll, qoffscreen.dll, qwebgl.dll)
3. dll took from here: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5 official site